# Buy SSL Certificate for intranet server from external CA

Tags: ssl

We are trying to secure an internal web site with SSL.
Currently we are using a self signed certificate that is not trusted by the site's users.

Is it possible to buy a certificate from a trusted CA and use it in an internal network?

Comment: Product reccomendations are off-topic on all [SE] sites. Please see the [FAQ] for details. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course - just dont forget that some CAs will want a valid email address at *exactly* the domain certified, so you will either need an externally visible hostname to your intranet site or get a wildcard cert (which will still need a reachable email address a level up, but not require you to expose your whole internal DNS zone externally. Rather expensive...)

For the more modern way, googling "Intranet ssl certificates" will find a few vendors... recommendations would definitely be "too localized".

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the type of network you have setup but the alternative here is to simply deploy your self-signed certificate as a trusted certificate.

If you are using Windows its pretty easy to do this with GPO policies.  I am sure there are other deployment methods as well for non-windows clients but they may not be as simple.  Ultimately though, deploying an internal Certificate Server is the holy grail as then you can trust any certificate you need to issue.

The simple deployment of a self-signed cert gives you a pretty easy solution without the yearly on-going cost of a public cert.  Obviously if you ever intend to extend the intranet site out to serve as an extranet this doesn't work too well for you.